# iOS: Facebook chat heads behaviour and animations

Tags: ios, facebook

This question is probably a little out of date, but I've been using the new Facebook for iOS with the "chat heads" feature (with the chat heads only present within the app), and was wondering how Facebook went about implementing this?  E.g. How did they handle the drag animations for the chat heads, and also (when clicking on the chat head) how did they manage to overlay a UITableView on top of the "base" UIViews in the background?

Is this all part of UIKit, or did they create their own classes to handle this?

Comment: Did you get any closer to an answer on this?

Answer (score 3):

To answer @StuartM's question in the comments, in the last couple of months I've had a bit more experience with UIKit, and I think I have a rough idea on how I would implement something like this if I was going to do it.

What I would do is for the chat head, create a styled UIButton and add it as subview to the main Window.  For the dragging, I would add a Gesture Recognizer to the UIButton to respond to the drags, and for the "snapping to edges" I would use iOS 7's new UIKit Dynamics (http://www.raywenderlich.com/50197/uikit-dynamics-tutorial).

As for showing the UITableView overlay with the chat history, I would use a Child View Controller (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH18-SW6) and as for the popping open animation, I would just use the default UIView animations, maybe using animation transactions as I'm not sure I can do everything with just the implicit animations?

And I think that should be it.  To be honest, I think anyone who has a handle on those frameworks should be able to build anything in their iOS apps, and if you were to create a "chat heads" like sample project in your spare time, should give you a pretty indepth knowledge of how those frameworks work.