# iOS: Make UIButton always display in front of all view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

i'm newbie in iOS.

Is there any sample code like "Touch Screen Home Button"
I found many sample like facebook chat head, but they can not display after back to home screen.

for example :
[iOS: Facebook chat heads behaviour and animations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17963620/ios-facebook-chat-heads-behaviour-and-animations)

Any help will be appreciate!

Comment: iOS does not allow this kind of thing.

Comment: You better consider a widget on notification center. (iOS 8)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, there is no way to keep buttons or other views showing once an application is no longer in the foreground.  Once the user presses the physical home button, the iOS will put an app in the background.

Answer (score 0):

You can use another UIWindow ,make it in front . and set windowLevel Higher.
perhaps this is useful for you  [demo](http://code4app.com/ios/%E7%8B%AC%E7%AB%8B%E4%BA%8Ewindow%E7%9A%84%E6%8C%89%E9%92%AE/522050f56803fa9e4d000000)